# new operator and array in C++

Tags: c++, memory

What is the meaning of this line:

```
int* p = new int[2,2];
```

in the following c++ code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* p = new int[2,2];
}
```

Comment: That doesn't compile, so it doesn't have much meaning.

Comment: @chris, [it compiles](http://ideone.com/XgS5l).

Comment: @iammilind, Oops, I left out the `new`, which gets past the errors of compile-time-determined array sizes. No wonder I was surprised to see it not compile; I did `int i[2,2];`.

Comment: In either case, @OP, turn on compiler warnings. You should get one for the comma there.

Answer (score 5):

```
int* p = new int[2,2];
```

effectively means

```
int* p = new int[2];
```

When comma operator is used, right most value is considered as final result.

Answer (score 2):

That comma between the two `2` is a "comma operator". It is rarely used in C++ and its semantic is to evaluate left part, ignore the result, and then evaluate right part. It is one of the few operators in which the order of evaluation of the operands is guaranteed (if you don't overload it).

A good compiler sould have emitted a warning because in your example the first expression has no side effects and `new int[2,2]` is exactly the same as `new int[2]`.

Note that other commas in C++ are NOT the comma operator... for example the commas between arguments in a function call are not commas operators and the order of evaluation of the arguments expression is not guaranteed. Worse than that may be an "order of evaluation" doesn't exist at all:

```
foo(f(g()), h());
```

in the line above the sequence in which the functions can be called could be for example `g`, `h`, `f` so you cannot say neither that the first argument was evaluated before the second nor that the second was evaluated before the first.

Answer (score 0):

It's creating an integer pointer and setting it to a new array.

Comment: Recommend you withdraw this as it's not a very complete answer.  The meaning of the comma in the example is too important to omit.